# Conditional update trigger

Tags: sql, if-statement, triggers, db2

I have the following SQL trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER datachange 
AFTER UPDATE OF Stand ON lenz.DATENSTAENDE
REFERENCING OLD AS olddata NEW AS newdata
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF (newdata.QUELLE LIKE 'LUCKY%') THEN
INSERT into lenz.inserttest(timefield, textfield, acttime) values(newdata.stand, newdata.quelle, CURRENT TIMESTAMP);
UPDATE lenz.updatetest set timefield = newdata.stand, acttime = CURRENT TIMESTAMP where textfield = newdata.quelle;     
END IF;
END@
```

The problem is that the insert and update should only trigger when the new data that is being inserted has the part string LUCKY at the begining.
For some reason at that point though the newdata content is unknown.

Examples:

```
'LUCKY CHIP YES', '2013-02-25', 'ALL LUCKY' -> should trigger
'ALL ALL BEST', '2014-06-28', 'WHAT IS THIS' -> should not trigger
```

How can I get this to work?

Thanks for your help.

TheVagabond

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot the ATOMIC after BEGIN.
Now it works.